# Woocommerce - displays price with tax, but charging without tax

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with wocommerce shop. I'm manually adding product to cart by below code:

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1, 0, array(), array( 'misha_custom_price' => $my_custom_price ) );
```

In my functions.php I have added below code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'rudr_custom_price_refresh' );

function rudr_custom_price_refresh( $cart_object ) {

    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $item ) {

        if( array_key_exists( 'misha_custom_price', $item ) ) {
            $item[ 'data' ]->set_price( $item[ 'misha_custom_price' ] );
        }
      
    }
    
}
```

On my checkout page, price is shown correctly, eg. 123$ (including 23$ as 23% VAT).
But when I go to pay, I see price without tax (100$).
Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I was using a plugin to manage checkout fields. I have hidden the "Country" field on the checkout page. This field must be visible for the tax to work properly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).